# Terminal Ubutu-20.04 don't works into VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-20.04, wsl-2

When i want open a new terminal of WSL (ubuntu 20.04 i´ve only this) into VS code i have this error:

*"Terminal process error "C: \ WINDOWS \ System32 \ wsl.exe '-d', 'Ubuntu-20.04 (default)'" at startup (exit code: 4294967295)."*

Before I didn't use that terminal within VS code but I think that before changing the name of the user's home directory, if it worked because after doing that when I opened the terminal from the outside it did not work for me so I uninstalled it and after I reinstalled it, now The terminal works for me outside of VS code but not inside, I don't know what to do.

I tried to do this but i don't have changes: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/troubleshoot-terminal-launch.